# Pre computing all paths in an N-ary tree to store in a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, tree

I am trying to convert an N-ary tree data structure that I have into a 2D matrix, each element of which contains the path to go from index i to index j. What is the best traversal algorithm I could use to create this matrix?

```
struct Node {
  unsigned int index;
  vector<Node*> children;
};
```

I can safely assume here that the node index would be unique and sequential, though the index ordering has no guarantees (for e.g.: index 0 would not necessarily be root)

The data structure I am thinking for the path matrix would be:

```
vector<unsigned int> path_matrix[NUM_NODES][NUM_NODES];
```

where `path_matrix[2][7]` would return the vector of integer index that would take me from node index 2 to node index 7.

Comment: Since the path between nodes in a tree is unique, consider to reduce the matrix to an 'path neighbor matrix' where element `(i, j)` contains the node id `u` of the first node to visit on the path `p_ij` from `i` to `j`. Alternatively, arbitrarily select one of your nodes the root and reduce the matrix to the adjacency matrix `A` of a digraph with all its edges oriented towards the root (there is exactly 1 neighbor to each non-root node, so `A` effectivly is a vector). To reconstruct `p_ij` ...

Comment: ... start at `i` and follow the edges given by `A` until a) you reach `j` ( done ) or b) you reach the root. in case of b), repeat for `j` until you reach `i` or the root. Copy the path nodes on the way appropriately. The latter approach will save you lots of storage ( `O(n)` vs. `O(n^2 * log n)` for naive implementations ) at the cost of at max `O(n)` of average runtime overhead ( depends on tree topology and start node selection / labelling scheme ).